# With latest iOS, can you make a custom emoji keyboard and insert emojis INTO TEXT (not as separate image)?

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

This has been asked in the past many times but I can't find a definitive answer that is up to date with the absolute latest iOS. Of course Id like this to be possible and I know in the past it was not, so I am asking-

is it at all possible with Swift to make a custom emoji (either in standalone app or using custom keyboard) and have the user be able to type this custom emoji (it would be an image) into SMS and have it type JUST AS TEXT DOES?

Ive read http://unicode.org/faq/emoji_dingbats.html and https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-an-emoji-app-for-iOS-with-original-alternative-symbols and I need to know if and how one would NOW go about 1. taking an image 2. allowing user to type it as text/unicode character in SMS, not as an image attachment like bitmoji or similar apps.

What does it take for an image to be treated and able to be sent in the same "text bubble" as a string of text? Can this be done in iOS9?